# Vue-Cookies Can't Get Cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, cookies

I am trying to setup an OAuth service from my Node.js back-end to my Vue front-end. Currently, the back-end appears to be working correctly; I am able to authenticate successfully with my google account and then am redirected to the appropriate UI View upon authentication. The cookie is also being stored.

[image: cookie in dev tools]

- My node service is running on localhost:3000
- My Vue UI is running on localhost:8080

I can access the cookie using 
`document.cookie`, and it shows:

```
"express:sess=<Data here>; express:sess.sig=<Data here>"
```

The problem is that I am using [vue-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies), and can't retrieve the cookie using `window.$cookies.get(...);`

In my `main.js` file I am importing vue-cookies:

```js
import VueCookies from "vue-cookies";
Vue.use(VueCookies);
window.$cookies.config("7D", "", "localhost");

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Here is my `router/index.js` where I am using that code:

```js
import Vue from "vue";

...
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    debugger;
    if (!window.$cookies) {
      next({
        path: "/login",
        params: { nextUrl: to.fullPath }
      });
    } else {
      const cookie = window.$cookies;
      if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.isAdmin)) {
        if (cookie.isAdmin) {
          next();
        } else {
          next({
            path: "/login",
            params: { nextUrl: to.fullPath }
          });
        }
      } else {
        next();
      }
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

If I try to log `window.$cookies.get("express:sess")`, it returns `null`. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I know that `window.$cookies` is defined from the console as well, because I can see all the methods/properties on that object.

If I create a cookie from the developer tools, with a name of "test", I **can** retrieve it:

```
> window.$cookies.get("test")
> "value"
```

**EDIT**:

If I change the cookie that I manually create to have a name of `test:test`, the output is null! Does the `:` character have something to do with why I can't retrieve the cookie??

```
> window.$cookies.get("test:test")
> null
```

**EDIT 2:**
I can do the following and see the cookies are there, but cannot access them for some reason.

```
window.$cookies.keys()
(3) […]
​
0: "express:sess"
​
1: "express:sess.sig"
​
2: "test"
​
length: 3
```

Comment: Could you just try `document.cookie` in console and check thee value?

Comment: @Rayon I did try that, please see above :)   I do get the appropriate response, but I am trying to avoid having to implement a cookie parser on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem relies on how vue-cookie manages cookies. if you take a look a the [set method](https://github.com/cmp-cc/vue-cookies/blob/master/vue-cookies.js#L87) you can see that vue-cookie encodes your values before storing the cookie.

**Example:**

let's say you store a cookie using vue-cookie:

```
$cookies.set('express:sess')
```

this will store the name of the cookie as `express%3Asess`
which is the result of `encodeURIComponent('express:sess')`

I recommend using a different library or just using native browser API's

Comment: I was actually looking at this exact piece of code as you posted this. For me, the problem is the `get` method. But the problem is still the same; the `:` character is being replaced in the code. [See here](https://github.com/cmp-cc/vue-cookies/blob/master/vue-cookies.js#L33)

Comment: That's right, that way the user of the library doesn't have to take care of the encoding. I'm not sure why they set it up this way, but there has to be a very good reason.

Comment: I guess you should use the same API's for setting the cookie and retrieving it. if the browser sets the cookie use the `cookie.get()` method.

Comment: I was able to change the name of the cookie on the back-end. But it looks like the standard for naming cookies specifically forbids certain characters: *A <cookie-name> can be any US-ASCII characters, except control characters, spaces, or tabs. It also must not contain a separator character like the following: ( ) < > @ , ; : \ " / [ ] ? = { }.*

Comment: I guess that's the reason. where did you find that? if you don't mind sharing

Comment: That was taken from [MDN Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie), but I would assume it applies to cookies in general. It definitely explains the vue-cookies implementation